# Dimmer not working?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

With a wall dimmer switch, is it possible for the on/off switch to operate but not the
dimmer?  Trying to isolate dimmer problem, between dimmer/switch or wiring?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the make and model of the dimmer switch?

Comment: The dimmer switch is a Lutron DVSC-603P-DS

Comment: What kind of light bulbs are you using?  Incandescent and LED respond differently

Comment: not all bulbs can dim

Comment: I am using incandescent which do work with my Lutron dimmer.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

On a typical North American "dumb" dimmer, the wall switch part is a mechanical, air-gap switch that may either be integrated with the knob or separate, but always switches the actual 120V hot line just like a regular wall switch does.  The dimming work, though, is done using a solid-state device called a *triac* that chops up the AC waveform in accordance with the setting on the knob.  As a result, if the triac fails short (a common failure mode for a triac that's seen too much electrical abuse), then you get a dimmer that has two settings: "off" and "full bright".